# Maximizing CFrameWndEx by moving it to the top of the screen

Tags: windows, mfc

When draging the caption of a CFrameWndEx based window to the top of the screen (on Windows 7) it is maximized. The problem is that it conflicts with the parameters returned in WM_GETMINMAXINFO that limits the window size. I want the window to be able to be maximized and I handle that when I receive the messages (WM_SYSCOMMAND or WM_SIZE) I receive when for example the user clicks maximize in the caption bar.

But what message should I receive when the window is maximized by dragging it to the top of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked it with Spy++.

I receive a normal WM_SIZW message with SIZE_MAXIMIZED, when I dock the window to the top of the screen.

<00409> 005B078A S WM_SIZE fwSizeType:SIZE_MAXIMIZED nWidth:1680 nHeight:988

Comment: Your are right - I missed that because the expected behaviour was prevented by what I did in WM_GETMINMAXINFO.